How to assign a value obtained by Stream to String variable in Java?
This is related to automation testing using Selenium and Java.
I am getting all elements of a column in a List<WebElement>.
After this, I want to get the first element of the above list using stream, take only the first 4 characters of that element/string using substring() and then store it in a String variable to perform further operations.
If I try to store it in a variable, it gives the below error

Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String

public class SeleniumEasyLandingPage {

 @FindBy(xpath = "//table/tbody/tr/td[3]")
    List<WebElement> assigneeColumn;

public void assigneeColumnOperations() {
        // below line is to print all of the elements in above list using stream - this is working fine
    assigneeColumn.stream().forEach(s->System.out.println(s.getText()));
    
        // below line is to print only first 4 characters of first element of above list - This is also working fine
    assigneeColumn.stream().limit(1).forEach(s->System.out.println("First Element - First Name:"+s.getText().substring(0, 4)));

        // below line is to store the above value in a String variable which gives error -
        String firstElementName=assigneeColumn.stream().limit(1).forEach(s->System.out.println("First Element - First Name:"+s.getText().substring(0, 4)));
        
    }

}


If you looked at the documentation of Stream.foreach(), you would see that this method accepts a Consumer and returns void.
In your statement, you're trying to assign void to a String variable
String firstElementName = assigneeColumn.stream().limit(1).forEach(s-> System.out.println(...));

which is why the compiler is signaling

Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String

If you need to retrieve the first element from your List, or the first element's four beginning characters, just use get() and then apply substring() to the result.
// read first element
String firstElementName = assigneeColumn.get(0);

// read first 4 characters of the first element
String firstElemFourChars = assigneeColumn.get(0).substring(0, 4);

Alternatively, if you really want to use streams, you can write:
// read first element
String firstElementName = assigneeColumn.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No elements found"));

// read first 4 characters of the first element
String firstElemFourChars = assigneeColumn.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No elements found")).substring(0, 4);


You need to use findAny method of Stream to get single value from it.
In your case you don't even need stream. Just use assigneeColumn.get(0) to get first value of a list.
